# How to find the maximum of $\boldsymbol{x}^T \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x}$ subject to $\boldsymbol{q}^T \boldsymbol{x}=1$?

Tags: matrices, optimization, quadratic-programming, non-convex-optimization

I want to solve the following problem in $\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb R^{n}$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & \boldsymbol{x}^T \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x}\\ \text{subject to} & \boldsymbol{q}^T \boldsymbol{x} = 1\\ & x_i \geq 0\end{array}$$

where matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$ is positive definite matrix and $x_i$ denotes the $i$-th entry of $\boldsymbol{x}$.

Actually, I have tried to use Lagrangian multiplier. I directly transformed the objective function to 
$-\boldsymbol{x}^T \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x} + \lambda ( \boldsymbol{q}^T \boldsymbol{x} - 1 )$ and take its first derivative and set that to zero.

However, the solution obtained did not maximize the objective function, it just makes $\boldsymbol{x}^T\boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x}$ smaller and smaller. Then I found that the solution of $\min_{\boldsymbol{x}} \boldsymbol{x}^T \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x}$ with the same constraints is the same with that of $\max_{\boldsymbol{x}} \boldsymbol{x}^T \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x}$.

Any comments would be appreciated!

Update
As comments suggested, I changed the situation to $x_i \geq 0, \forall i$. Thus for example, when $\boldsymbol{A}= \left[\begin{matrix} {2 \; 0\\ 0 \;1 }\end{matrix} \right]$ and $\boldsymbol{q} = [1,1]^T$. The problem has a solution $\boldsymbol{x} = [1 ,0]^T$ that maximize the objective function. Can this extend to more general case?

Comment: Geometric intuition should suggest that in a noticeable number of cases $\sup\{x^TAx\,:\, q^Tx=1\land \forall i, x_i> 0\}=\infty$ (specifically, cases where $\neg(q>0)$)

Comment: If you are looking for a numerical solution, cplex/gurobi can solve this.

Comment: Thanks for your kind comment. I still want to figure it out analytically.

Comment: Thanks for you comment, but when $x_i \geq 0$, it seems the question have a maximum at the boundary.

Comment: Is $q_i > 0, \forall i$?

Comment: Yes，$q_i>0 \for all i$

Comment: With the constraint $x_i>0$, I don't think there is any closed-form solution.

Comment: positive definite，sorry for that mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\mathbf q > \mathbf 0$, the feasible region $\{\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n : \mathbf q^{\mathsf T} \mathbf x = 1, \mathbf x \ge \mathbf 0\}$ is bounded (we have $x_i \in [0, \frac1{q_i}]$ for each $i$). It's also closed, so the maximum of $f(\mathbf x) = \mathbf x^{\mathsf T} \!A \mathbf x$ must be achieved somewhere in the feasible region.

Because $f(\mathbf x)$ is convex, this maximum must be at an extreme point, and this feasible region has only $n$ extreme points: for each $i$, we can get one of them by setting $x_i = \frac1{q_i}$ and all other entries to $0$. This point has objective value $f(\mathbf x) = \frac{A_{ii}}{q_i^2}$. Now just compare the values $\frac{A_{11}}{q_1^2}, \dots, \frac{A_{nn}}{q_n^2}$ and pick the largest.

Comment: Nice solution. The maximum of a convex function over the polyhedron is achieved at one of its vertices.