# Approximating large quadratic optimization problems

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming, non-convex-optimization, principal-component-analysis

For some positive-definite matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{K \times K}$ I want to solve the quadratic optimization problem
$$\max_{x\in [0,1]^K} x^T A x \\ \text{s.t.} \\ \sum_{i=1}^{K}x_{i}=1$$
The problem is that $K$ is very large. Are there useful approximations to the quadratic form $x^TAx$ that would allow an approximate solution? Is dimensionality reduction of $A$ a useful idea?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3817221/339790 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3594469/339790

Comment: Yes, it's fundamentally the same as the second one, with $q = \mathbf 1$. The solution is the same : since the objective function is convex, the maximum is at one of the extremum points, that is one of $(0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots,0)$. You have $K$ points to check, this should be quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are taking $\max$ then your problem is not convex, and you are having serious issues. If you wanted $\min$ *and* did not insist on the positivity, then the solution is just $A^{-1} \mathbb{1}/\mathbb{1}^T A^{-1} \mathbb{1},$ where $\mathbb{1}$ is the vector of all ones.
If you did not have the sum constraint either, then you are in luck with $\max$ - it is just the eigenvector of the largest eigenvalue, which is easy to find by iterative methods.